# Redirect all naked domain urls to subdomain(www) urls preserving the url, except for one page on IIS/ASP.NET

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, asp.net-4.0, httpmodule

Whats the best way to achieve the above? I do know that it can be achieved at HttpModule level. Is it possible just via web.config(easier and faster to code execute).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to do this with the URL rewrite module through the web.config :

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect naked domains to www.domain.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^noredirect/forthis/page\.aspx$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^noredirect/forthis/page-as-well\.aspx$" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^noredirect/forthis/page-as-well-too\.aspx$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Or if you really only have a single page that doesn't need to be redirected, it can be even shortened to:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="Redirect naked domains to www.domain.com" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^noredirect/forthis/page\.aspx$" negate="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: See SO question [IIS7 URL Rewriting: How not to drop HTTPS protocol from rewritten URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608994/iis7-url-rewriting-how-not-to-drop-https-protocol-from-rewritten-url) for handling HTTPS/HTTP redirects.