# 301 Redirect from app.com to www.app.com + always-https in an Azure Cloud Service with MVC app?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure, amazon-web-services, dns

I have an MVC application being hosted in an Azure Cloud Service.  I need to redirect all requests for:

- app.com
- http://app.com
- sub.app.com
- https:app.com

to

- https://www.app.com
- https://www.app.com
- https://sub.app.com
- https://www.app.com

respectively.  Always ensuring a subdomain (or www), and always enforcing https.  I *can* do this at the application level in something like global.asax, but this feels wrong.  I'm currently using Amazon's Route53 to handle my DNS needs, though I'm not sure if DNS is the right layer for this concern either.  What is the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTTPS

Given that it is an MVC app you can enforce https by using the `[RequireHttps]` attribute. Personally I normally have a base controller that all my other controllers inherit from and I stick `[RequireHttps]` on that base controller.
Alternatively, register it as a global filter like so:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());

    //... other stuff
}
```

(copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3285179/11534)

### Redirecting from the naked url

As far as redirecting from the naked subdomain to www you probably want to look at Url Rewriting, which you can stick in web.config. See [Redirect all naked domain urls to subdomain(www) urls preserving the url, except for one page on IIS/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195315/redirect-all-naked-domain-urls-to-subdomainwww-urls-preserving-the-url-except) for a very similar example.
I have to admit that I have not used the url rewriting a lot so maybe someone else can help with more specific details on how to achieve your specific requirement...

Comment: Thanks!  RE the HTTPS attribute - is this better/worse than using a reqrite module in web.config?

Comment: I think it's much of a muchness. Personally I find it easier to use the attribute but I don't think there is much in it.