# Redirecting non-WWW to WWW in an Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, redirect, azure

I have a domain with Godaddy, and a website on the Azure websites infrastructure. What I want to achieve is to use only the www version of my domain. If a user enters "example.com" in their browser I want them to be redirected to "www.example.com".

The site is hosting a ASP.Net MVC 5 app if that makes a difference. How do I configure this?

Comment: This is not azure websites specific. Look for questions concerning redirecting naked domains to www on IIS like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13195315/468244).

Comment: @SimonOpelt Thanks. I'm new to the web technology, don't yet know what I don't know. Many thanks, I will give that a whirl.

Comment: Would this just be a temporary 302 redirect ? A perm 301 redirect using rules in the web.config would be better for SEO.

Comment: and how would you do that?

Answer (score 25):

add this code this code under `<system.webServer>` section

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to www">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: @EthanTowne I am using the rewrite module for Azure websites.  No configuration was necessary other than modifying the web.config.

Comment: This doesn't actually work. The correct structure is `<rewrite><rules><rule name="Redirect to www">`. You're missing the `<rules>` element. If you add your code to the Web.Config, you'll break your website

Comment: In what file is this supposed to be added?

Comment: it will be added to web.config under <system.webServer> section. First ensure you have UrlRewrite module is installed properly on server

Comment: I copied your code, but it does not redirect to the exact URL, for example, https://[domain].com/blog is redirecting to https://www.[domain].com/. How can I redirect by only adding www in the current URL?

Answer (score 21):

If you want a REAL redirection (i.e. when a user types `example.com` then the address in the browser automatically changes to `www.example.com`) then you have two options:

1. Using the forwarding feature offered by GoDaddy (you can find it in the GoDaddy dashboard (domain details page). In this way you can point `example.com` to a GoDaddy IP that responds with a redirection to `www.example.com`
2. Write some code in ASP.NET that detects when the address is missing "www." and then redirecting to `www.example.com`

However, if you just want the users that type `example.com` to get the same content as users typing `www.example.com` and you don't mind people seeing `example.com` without www in their address bar, then proceed as following:

1. Get the virtual IP address associated to your Azure website: from the Azure management portal click on your website, go to the dashboard section and click Manage Domains. You should get something like "The IP address to use when you configure A records: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx".
2. Go to GoDaddy and set an A record with "Host" to `@` and "Points to" set to the IP found at step 1
3. Add a CNAME record with "Host" set to `awverify` and "Points to" set to the address of your azure website prefixed with `awverify` (for example `awverify.mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`)
4. Add a CNAME record with "Host" set to `www` and "Points to" set to the address of your azure website (for example `mywebsite.azurewebsites.net`)
5. Save the zone file in GoDaddy
6. Go back to windows azure in the "Manage Domains" section of your website and add both `example.com` and `www.example.com` to the list of domain names.

If you get any error at step 6, just wait some hours to let the DNS changes to propagate and retry.

More info here: https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

Comment: Thanks, this worked on Azure with Uniregistry perfectly. It wasn't clear what was meant by "add subdomain" in the Azure instructions but your 'awverify' example cleared that up. I had an SSL cert covering both domains but one was not resolving. This should be the accepted answer for Azure websites.

Answer (score 8):

In **ASP.NET Core MVC**, add this to the `Startup.cs` `Configure()` method.

```
            app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions()
                // redirect non www to www.
                .AddRedirectToWwwPermanent()

                 // While we are at it, let's also redirect http to https.
                .AddRedirectToHttpsPermanent()
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a generic MatchAll with negate=true, I prefer to catch only the naked domain and redirect if it is a match.  This works well for Azure since I am only interested in a single domain and then I don't have to write a bunch of exclusions for localhost,  localtest.me, subdomains, etc.

Here is the rule... just change `example` in the pattern to your domain:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect To WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{URL}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```