# Azure Applicate gateway - none www to www redirection

Tags: azure, kentico, azure-application-gateway

We have a website build in Kentico 10 and hosted on Azure, and it has Application gateway as well.

Is there any way we can do the redirection from none www to www using via Azure portal. Without using rewrite in web.config

eg: like we redirect to http to https

Comment: If you are using `Godaddy` you can use the forward feature,take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22145705/7073340)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do a rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

In Application gateway you have a feature called Listener to Listener redirection. This is how it works.

Client(uses HTTP) ---> Application Gateway Listener (80) --->redirects to Listener (443) --> Backend server(Only listens on port 443)

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/redirect-http-to-https-powershell#add-a-listener-and-redirection-rule