# Rewrite url with correct HTTP/HTTPS scheme

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have the following rule in my web.config file. As you can see it takes all subdomains and redirects to 'www.'

I also have an HTTP module that does switching between HTTP and HTTPS on the OnPreRequestHandlerExecute event. From what I have read and understood, this occurs after the rewrite but I could be wrong.

This code actually works in Firefox, transferring to www. then HTTPS where necessary, however it doesn't work in either Chrome or IE, maintaining the HTTP scheme.

I would like to make some changes to the code below so that the scheme is carried over rather than just assume HTTP which is does at the moment.

```
<rewrite xdt:Transform="Insert">
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to www">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10227936/1443490 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS7 URL Rewriting: How not to drop HTTPS protocol from rewritten URL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608994/iis7-url-rewriting-how-not-to-drop-https-protocol-from-rewritten-url)