# URL Rewrite - FQDN to another domain

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Hi all and thank you for any assistance.

We have a backup server that is accessible through it's FQDN, let's call it "ABC-Backups.Very.Long.Domain.Name" This backup server has the capability to have self service restores for our employees. We have everything working through the FQDN, however, we want to make the name friendlier and encrypt it with SSL (HTTPS). We currently have a URL Rewrite rule in place to force HTTP to HTTPS and that is working. We have a wildcard certificate *.BusinessName.com. We have applied this cert to the binding and entered an on-prem DNS record to point ABC-Backup.BusinessName.com to the server's Ip Address. So far everything with the new name is working as expected.

However, we want to also forward any requests to ABC-Backups.Very.Long.Domain.Name to ABC-Backups.BusinessName.com. I have tried using a CNAME record in DNS, which didn't work. I tried HTTP redirect, which ended up in an error of being redirected too many times. I also have installed the URL Rewrite module, but thus far I have been unsuccessful. I have the below Redirect in place using Matches the Pattern and Regular Expressions.

^(ABC-Backups.Very.Long.Domain.Name)/(.*)$

With a redirect to
https://ABCBackups.BusinessName.com/(R:2)

Permanent 301

When I enter https://ABC-Backups.Very.Long.Domain.Name/Login.aspx it brings up our login page and does not redirect to ABCBackups.BusinessName.com as I would expect it to. I am not sure what I am missing, but any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

-Jon

Comment: Mistake 1 https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this rule is what you want. It can redirect correctly in test. Please try it.

```
 <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="ABC-Backups.Very.Long.Domain.Name" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://ABC-Backups.BusinessName.com/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! You got me halfway there and this post finished it off!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608994/iis7-url-rewriting-how-not-to-drop-https-protocol-from-rewritten-url

Thank you for your assistance! I was missing the Conditions piece.