# What is wrong with this rewrite rule

Tags: redirect, iis

I am attempting to create a redirect rule to direct all traffic to one of my pages on my old site to my new site. I have created this rules in the parent web.config on my old IIS server:

```
            <rule name="redirect to survey domain" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="takesurvey" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^emory.zanek.net$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://survey.zanek.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
```

Essentially I want to redirect all traffic for the specific page takesurvey to a new survey domain. So if the user navigates to:

https://emory.zanek.net/goalw4/takesurvey.aspx?id=fasidisdf

it should redirect to:

https://survey.zanek.net?id=fasidisdf

However, When I applied the rule, and then I navigate to https://emory.zanek.net/goalw4/takesurvey.aspx?id=fasidisdf, it just hangs forever. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying {HTTP_HOST} but both of your URLs are HTTPS which operates on a different TCP protocol.

For your simple scenario I would just change {HTTP_HOST} to {HTTPS} in your input line.

For more information about this and robust ways to implement more complex/multiple cross types, see the link below.

[Web config rewrite HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608994/iis7-url-rewriting-how-not-to-drop-https-protocol-from-rewritten-url)

Comment: Thanks @user4074875. Making progress. I made the adjustment (and it makes sense). However, now when i navigate to the old url (https://emory.zanek.net/goalw4/takesurvey.aspx?id=fasidisdf) it just hangs indefinitely. Any thoughts?